# Ask for email or phone after "Add to cart" button clicked in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filter, hook

I'm looking for a way to create a feature in WooCommerce that would ask for a guests email or phone right after he clicks on the "Add to cart" button.
Here would be the scenario I'm planning to build:

1. Guest user clicks on the "Add to cart" for a specific product
2. All WooCommerce functions that would normally follow this operation get paused
3. An input field appears asking for email or phone
4. Once the user submits the data all of the remaining functions that were paused continue running (product is added to the cart, redirects are made etc.)

I would very much appreciate to know how to perform the 1st and 2nd steps in this scenario. Maybe there is a specific hook or filter that can be used to pause and then resume the executions? Or maybe there is a PHP function that can break and then resume execution of a process?

So far I have found this filter `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` that can be used to validate if all is OK and then either Adds the product to the cart or redirects to product page and displays an error message, however this does not allow me to stop the process and present additional data to the user.

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe you should just make it easier for yourself **1)** An input field asking for email or phone **2)** As long as no correct value is entered in the input field, the add to cart button is disabled. **OR** as you describe it, I see the following solution. **1)** You add an extra add to cart button which looks identically the same and which covers the real add to cart button, but only serves to make the field appear. **2)** If the field is filled in correctly, hide your custom add to cart button and trigger the real add to cart button click. For both solutions, jQuery will have to be used.

Comment: This is a good idea and one that I already had up in my sleeve, but I was still looking maybe there is a way to do it using the tools WooCommerce provides.